How can I install ggpattern?
I tried to install ggpattern using these commands one by one but did not work. I tried to install rlang alone as it shows in error but it could not be installed too. My R version is 4.2.3 (2023-03-15).
install.packages("ggpattern")

library(remotes)
remotes::install_github("coolbutuseless/ggpattern")

install.packages('ggpattern',repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')



install.packages("ggpattern")
also installing the dependency ‘rlang’


  There are binary versions available but the source
  versions are later:
          binary source needs_compilation
rlang      1.1.2  1.1.4              TRUE
ggpattern  1.0.1  1.1.3             FALSE

Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation? (Yes/no/cancel) Yes
installing the source packages ‘rlang’, ‘ggpattern’

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rlang_1.1.4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 767041 bytes (749 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 749 KB

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/ggpattern_1.1.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3501869 bytes (3.3 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 3.3 MB

* installing *source* package ‘rlang’ ...
** package ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rlang’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/rlang’
* restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/rlang’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rlang’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘ggpattern’ ...
** package ‘ggpattern’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace ‘rlang’ 1.1.0 is already loaded, but >= 1.1.3 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘ggpattern’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/ggpattern’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ggpattern’ had non-zero exit status

